# Web Sockets vs WebRTC for sending MediaStream to the webserver

Tags: websocket, webrtc, getusermedia

I want to send a `mediaStream` created from `getUserMedia` up to a server.

What is best to use, WebRTC or WebSockets?

My gut tells me that WebRTC is specifically made for video and audio data, so this is the one to go for - but everything I read about WebRTC makes it seem like its only for peer to peer connections.

I'm going to have to learn everything about WebRTC or WebSockets so I can get my mediaStreams on the webserver - I just want to make sure I am not wasting my time learning about the wrong one.

Many thanks.

Comment: For a server side WebRTC connection, you could use a MCU like [Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway).

Comment: Read about both and then think for yourself which is more suitable for your project.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have time to research into both, I could do with knowing which is the best to send the `mediaStream` up to my server, so I can then devote my time to reading about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read online [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.media/pos7woJMimo) I would recommend WebRTC for sending your data to the server :)